# SharePoint Framework Extension : Custom Action not activated on site even after successful deployment in AppCatlog

Tags: office-365, custom-actions, solution-deployment, spfx-extensions

[image][Screen Shot for the App Catlog ]

Hello everyone,

I deployed a SharePoint Framework Extension in the App Catalog for my office 365 CDN.

Although in the App Catalog it shows successfully deployed, and I added the app for a site on the same tenant however I still don't see custom action on this site. (Please see below the screen shot for app Catalog)

Is there some log or some information that i can use to know why is my app not showing up on the site ..

A quick answer will be really helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, seems the custom action was successfully deployed on the List since I used the default setting for ListView CommandSet with Registration Id = 100.
For Documents library it worked once I set the Registration Id =101, redeployed the sppkg, removed the app from site and re-added it.

Hope it helps someone !